# Fire function within jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, plugins, bind

I have dynamically created increment and decrement buttons for certain <input> html elements (specifically for numeric inputs), however I cannot for the life of me how to figure out how to bind an action through the plugin function.

I want to do it specifically this way as these arrows will be used on many different types of forms that minus and add values (e.g. %, money etc.) which affect certain visual elements.

The function looks around the lines of:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.addIncrementArrows = function (min, max, interval, fastInterval, event) {

        var input = this;

        /*Other building things go here*/

        var timeoutDownArrow;
        var intervalDownArrow;
        //clicking button down for 1 second fires '-' actions
        $(this).parent().children(".downarrow").mousedown(function () {
            timeoutDownArrow = setTimeout(function () {
                intervalDownArrow = setInterval(function () {
                    changeValue(-fastInterval);

                    //how to do event here?

                }, 90);
            }, 750);
        }).bind("mouseup mouseleave", function () {
            clearTimeout(timeoutDownArrow);
            clearInterval(intervalDownArrow);
        });

    };
}(jQuery));
```

Simply what I need to declare to make it have the arrows as follows:

```
formnamehere.addIncrementArrows(0, 100, 1, 5, event);
```

If it's possible: how could I bind an action to the button within .addIncrementArrows()?

Comment: add 1 param to plugin function function (elem,min, max, interval, fastInterval, event) .  then use it like $.addIncrementArrows($('#formnamehere'),0, 100, 1, 5, event);

Comment: add your html code so will create example or create fiddle

Comment: how you attach using this when there is no button attach ?? here you want to attach button on click event then in inside plugin function how you get this as button reference ?

Comment: The button is created inside .addIncrementArrows() jQuery("<div/>").insertAfter(input);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of research I came to a conclusion:

1 - Changed the function to run inside .addIncrementArrows() as a named run-time function:

```
var setSliderPercentage = function (percent) {
    //do stuff here
}
```

2 - Pass the function into the plugin as a variable name

```
percentageForm.addIncrementArrows(0, 100, 1, 5, setSliderPercentage);
```

3 - Ran the passed function within the addIncrementArrows() plugin.

```
$.fn.addIncrementArrows = function (min, max, interval, fastInterval, event) {
    var input = this;
    if (max === false) max = Infinity; //infinity and beyond!

    //Other stuff here

    //make the it auto increment or decrement every 100ms when 'holding down' the button after 1 second
    var timeoutUpArrow;
    var intervalUpArrow;
    $(uparrow).mousedown(function () {
        timeoutUpArrow = setTimeout(function () {
            intervalUpArrow = setInterval(function () {
                changeValue(fastInterval);
                //
                if (typeof event != "undefined") event(input.val());
                //
            }, 90);
        }, 750);
    }).bind("mouseup mouseleave", function () {
        clearTimeout(timeoutUpArrow);
        clearInterval(intervalUpArrow);
    });

}
```